if a rock (like 6.4 cm or 2.5 inches) had gravity that was comparable to a planet or other large-ish astral body?
for context I have a character who's basically an earthbender but they can alter the gravity of the earth they manipulate. What would this do if it was, for example, used as a projectile. Yes there is a limit for them it's like around moon-small planet level

This isn't quite the density of neutron star material... but the point is the same. You might as well make it a black hole. Maybe the mass of the moon? Even that would be a big honking city-flattening ocean-draining deal. To be honest, there's such a thing as too much science. Does it matter what the specifics of the rock are so long as your described effects are consistently applied in your story?

probably not, and I forgot to mention (which was dumb of me because this is probably crucial information), but its less real gravity and more of an approximation of how gravity would work or smth. You make a lot of sense so I'll probably go with that, but one more thing: would increasing their gravity make them stronger projectiles? Like how Star Rage from Jujutsu Kaisen works

There is no reason to believe that increasing the gravity of a projectile without increasing its mass would make it "stronger".

Do you mean the surface gravity of the rock equals the surface gravity of earth/moon, or rather the surface gravity of earth/moon shrunk to the size of a rock? That makes a teeny tiny bit of a difference.

@nefariousfiend The simple answer to your question is "no." I'm oversimplifying, but gravity kinda reflects the force of an extended rubber band trying to pull its two ends together. In other words, it would only make the projectile more powerful if the projectile emerged somewhere up in the sky and the victim was on the ground directly below it, because that's what the gravity wants to do... pull the two objects together along the shortest possible line. We get a lot of "explain my superpower with science" questions, since is rarely accommodating.

Kill Everyone in the Vicinity Due to Tidal Stresses
If, in violation of all known laws of physics, a small rock maintained its normal mass and radius while exerting the gravitational pull of a quintillion-tonne body, the gravitational force for something in contact with its surface would be ~6.6M earth gravities.
But the force of gravity reduces by the inverse square of the distance to the centre of the mass, so someone twice as far away (3.2cm from the surface of the rock) would only experience about 1.6M earth gravities.
By the time you get to ten metres away from the rock, the effect is only about seventy times Earth's gravity.  Still more than enough to yank someone towards the object, but less ridiculous numbers.  Unfortunately, this is likely to lead to spaghettification for everyone near the rock.
All this is assuming that the "earthbender" can make the rock produce the gravitational effect of having a mass of a quintillion tonnes without actually having that mass.  If you just mean "the gravity on the surface of the stone is equal to the gravity of a moon", then the answer is "nothing major, everyone's fine".
Edit: for clarity, the last statement is in reference to the effects of that gravity.  The same inverse square applies, so if we use Earth's moon's surface gravity (0.16g), by the time you're even a metre away the effective pull is less than a hundredth of a g.

as someone who is not smart, correct me if I'm wrong but I'm going to assume you meant in the first part if it actually had moon gravity, and the second part being just the affect, so basically the rock can pull people in but they can jump off of it like with the moon

Not at all, no. It's maybe counterintuitive to someone not familiar with geodesics (the way gravity works), but the closer to the centre of mass you get, the stronger the gravity is - on the moon you're just over 1000 miles (1700 km) away - if you were a few inches from the centre of mass the gravity would correspond to the description above. That doesn't work if you fall into a hole on the moon as much of the mass would then be behind you as you go towards the centre, but when all the mass is concentrated in a small lump, the the gravity's effects get pretty impressive. @nefariousfiend

@nefariousfiend That is not a correct assumption.  Gravity is a force produced by masses' distortion of space-time.  You're proposing an increase in gravity without an increase in mass.  The total "gravity" of a quintillion-tonne object (something planetoid-sized) can be expressed two ways - either the gravity that would result from that mass, or the gravitational force experienced on the surface of such an object.  Both options are in my answer.

@nefariousfiend -and no, if it's the first case (the gravity that would be associated with a moon's mass), no one is ever jumping off the rock; they'd be dead before they even touched it.

@nefariousfiend I'm just guessing here .. but perhaps if you changed the question by defining 1. the size of your rock 2. perhaps most importantly, not defining the 'actual gravity' it has 3. and instead defining the 'equivalent gravity' (as it where) you want to be experienced by people 4. and then at what distance from the object you wanted that experienced .. there may be a small possibility that you 'might' get something (just a little bit) closer to what you were after if you adjust your question thus? .. [ponders] but then again maybe not

I think you are not stressing the devastating effect of the first option enough. I think it could effectively be a planet killer, if a lot of earths mass is attracted more to that rock than to earths center, earths mantle would probably break around you, while even solid rock buckles under the gravitational pull, ripping apart continents and a part of the planet, maybe killing the whole eco-system like the eruption of a massive super-volcano?

@Falco - no, as I indicate, the drop-off as a result of the inverse square means that collateral damage to the planet as a whole is actually surprisingly minimal.  Substantial gravitational effects will more or less cease (<0.1g) a little more than 200m from the rock.  Tensile strengths of most materials will prevent damage well within that radius.  It's only when you get within 100m or so that things start getting particularly dicey.

Thank you for the additional clarification

The pull between this object and the earth would be enormous, namely the weight of the earth if the gravity on the object is 1g or even a small fraction. The object would simply sink through the crust and end up somewhere close to the center of the earth. whereupon the gravity of the earth would take on this additional gravity. Unless this object is pea size or under, the force would not be strong enough to cause neutron star material.

This would be true if the object had the mass equivalent to the gravity it's producing, but the OP postulates that the gravity is present without the associated mass, so the effect of the earth's gravity on the rock would be the same as the earth's gravity on any similar pebble.

@jdunlop all known gravity the forces on the 2 bodies are equal. If somehow they are not, and it exerts a force on its surroundings that does not got exerted on itself, the earth will leave the suns orbit, and go flying across the galaxy. The earth is still a large mass that is moved by gravitational fields.

Eventually true, if the false gravity postulated by the OP persisted for a lengthy time.  But in the short term, from how the phenomenon is described, yes, the forces would be unbalanced because gravity would be being "produced" that didn't have concomitant mass.

Let us try to imagine that the Earth pulls on the stone as if it had the weight of a stone in Earth's gravity field directed towards Earth, and that the stone pulls on Earth as if it had the weight of Earth in the gravity field of Earth directed towards the stone. Clearly these two objects are pulled towards each other, and with enormous force. The result is as @camelccc wrote.

If you’re allowed to interpret “planetary masses” as “up to a limit greater than approximately 7.5 earth masses”, then the object will have a great enough density and mass that it will entirely reside within its own Schwarzschild radius. Congratulations, your character can now create black holes at will.
Why use this as a projectile? If you can alter the density of rocks at will, just create planetary-mass black holes under your opponent and un-create them before the tidal force kills you too. Don’t even use it as a weapon: it’s the ultimate deterrent. “Unless you do exactly as I say, I’ll open a black hole and destroy the atmosphere, killing us all.” Or the character could even bluff that, in their godlike capability to spontaneously cause mass production, they can also survive it! “ Unless you do exactly as I say, I’ll open a black hole kill *you in particular.”
The moral of the story? Be careful about what powers you give your characters.

It all depends on what you mean by "planet-like". jdunlop's answer has rigid adherence to the inverse-square law (which is perfectly reasonable), but one could equally decide that "planet-like gravity" means "accelerates things nearby uniformly towards the centre 9.8ms-1 ".
At which point we have a few interesting locations -- a region of doubled gravity above the stone, a region of weightlessness beneath the stone, and potentially regions to the side where there is a significant horizontal component to the gravitational force.
It's not clear how extensive this modified gravitational field should be: our simplified assumptions only break down for the earth after a few hundred kilometers, but it's possible it's much more localised for a smaller rock. (Yes, this is very handwavey).
As the moving rock's area of effect reaches an object, it would experience gravity at 45 degrees at increased by a factor of 1.4 (√2). Structures like bridges and houses expect gravity to be downwards and are likely to collapse. People will fall over unless prepared. As the rock continues past them, this will move towards a brief moment of weightlessness, which may lead to them losing contact with the ground. Gravity will then begin to tug in the opposite direction, with a whiplash like effect, and hurling people towards the direction of the stone.
